# Purpose of @Component annotation on spring-boot-starter-jersey resources in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, jersey, spring-boot, spring-annotations

```
@Path("test")
public TestResource {

    @GET
    public Response testGet() {
        return Response.ok().build();
    }

}
```

From the spring boot documentation, the section on JAX-RS and Jersey, "All the registered endpoints should be @Components with HTTP resource annotations (@GET etc.), e.g.". The above resource still works without the @Component annotation. What would I be breaking by leaving out the @Component annotation?

Comment: The `TestResource` instance won't be managed by Spring.

Comment: Rightly said by @SotiriosDelimanolis. `TestResource` is not managed by Spring but Jersey thus it doesn't matter if you annotate it using `@Component` or `@Controller` etc.

Comment: Is there an advantage or disadvantage to having `TestResource` managed by spring as opposed to jersey? @SotiriosDelimanolis @user2004685

Comment: The life-cycles of the two resources will be different. For details look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63931292/3213514).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"To enable JAX-RS resources to work Spring functionality that requires proxying, such as Spring transaction management (with @Transactional), Spring Security and aspect oriented programming (such as @Aspect), the resources must themselves be managed by Spring, by annotating with @Component, @Service, @Controller or @Repository:"

Comment: Additionally you must also be aware that the life-cycle of Spring managed resources is different then normal Jersey managed resources. For details look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63931292/3213514).